# Laser, wire, and a circle of light

Tags: reflection, laser

So, when I point a laser at a piece of wire (pointed at a specific angle), a circle of light appears on a wall behind it (see image below). I am trying to see why this happens and if there are any readings on this. Could anyone give some tips on what I should search for or any references?

[image]
([screenshot from this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q_4SNbpBfo))

So this is a problem for a physics tournament, but I haven't tried it myself yet. However I have found a video depicting what I mean.

Comment: A reference for what, exactly? It's not all clear to me what it is you are doing that you want to search.

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear, I'm new to this and was in a rush typing up the question. Will edit shortly. Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem for a physics tournament, and the problem is basically written exactly as I asked, so I'm completely lost too.

Comment: I see what you mean now, the video really helped. I've added a screenshot from the video so that others can see what you mean without clicking away (as well as add some grammar fixes).

Comment: I suspect that it's going to be related to diffraction about the sharp point of the pin.

Comment: I found this https://www.penflip.com/ErnWong/circle-of-light

Comment: Hello Tao Tien. I'm working on this problem. It seems you've worked on it. If you have worked on this project, I will be happy to have your E-mail to talk about this problem with you more. would you give me your E-mail address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I did it myself and figured it out. It's just really simple reflection.

[image]

Basically the wire acts as a mirror, albeit a curved one. Because the light from a laser is straight, we won't have messy light. When a laser reflects off of a flat surface, it keeps going straight. However when it reflects off a small curved surface (i.e a wire), the laser rays all go different ways, and create a circle of light.

Comment: From the screenshot, the circle looks closed and uniform in intensity, which is odd if reflection is the sole cause.

Comment: But how about the dark fringes?