# A Circle of light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I'm working on a project that refers to optics. the question says when a laser beam is aimed to a wire ( perpendicular to the surface ), a circle of light then will be seen on a the surface. 
I somehow know its explanation, but now I'm investigating it. I want to know the effect of the angle between laser beam and the wire on the circle features like its circumference, ...

[image]Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicates): [Why does a circle of light appear when I shine a laser pointer at a wire](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167220/) and [Laser, wire, and a circle of light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161924/).

Comment: Chris Mueller they have asked for the explanation but I've asked the effect of the angle between laser beam and the wire on the circle features such as its circumference

Comment: No One can answer my question, really?!?!?!?!??!?!?!/1

Comment: I think the problem is that no one wants to take the time to.  I think you are perfectly capable of answering it yourself though.  Start by thinking of the wire as a flat mirror; how far from the wire would the spot land?  How is this distance related to the radius of the circle of light?