# Diffraction in Circle of light?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I'm working on a project that refers to optics. the question says when a laser beam is aimed to a wire ( perpendicular to the surface ), a circle of light then will be seen on a the surface. I somehow know its explanation, but there's something I need to know.
Dose Diffraction happen in this phenomenon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laser, wire, and a circle of light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161924/)

Comment: Related question (by same user): [A circle of light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/171848/).

Comment: No, diffraction isn't important.  The phenomenon is purely based on reflection.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your wire (any direction) we have diffraction but I think this question can;t be solve by diffraction .  Just experiment it : If after glowing your light we have complete shadow in the back of the wire , we haven't diffraction but If not , we have that .