# Is this picture sign of diffraction?

Tags: optics

Please tell me that can it be the sign of diffraction?
I mean can diffracted rays make this pattern?
[image]

Comment: That looks to me like the [circle you get when reflecting a laser off a wire](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161924/laser-wire-and-a-circle-of-light). While there is some diffraction in the fine structure (it's almost impossible to avoid some interference when firing lasers around) the circular shape is due to reflection not diffration.

Comment: The finer structures visible in, and especially around the ring, could partially be speckle patterns (and therefore are a result of diffraction).

Comment: Hello John Rennie. Sir, it seems you haved worked on this project ( circle of light by aiming a laser to a wire ). if you have worked, i would be happy to have your E-mail to discuss about this phenomenon. can you give me your E-mail?